# Unable to spawn a python shell using winpexpect

Tags: python, windows, pexpect

I'm trying to spawn a python process using winpexpect, but `test = winpexpect.winspawn('python.exe')` is failing to do so. The command itself does not throw an error, but when I try `test.expect('>>>')` the process is timing out.

This behavior is not observed when I try to spawn a *cmd.exe* or some other process.

Can a python process be spawned using winpexpect? Am I doing some thing wrong?

PS: Python path is added to my PATH environment variable

Comment: have you tried to pass `-i` command-line option, to force interactive mode? Also, recent `pexpect` versions have partial Windows support. Consider using `multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures` or similar instead of running `python.exe` as a subprocess manually.

Comment: This helps, thanks! When a prompt comes for user input in the child process, _InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read_ error is thrown. Do you by any chance know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) has suggested, forcing the process to interactive mode helped.

`test = winpexpect.winspawn('python.exe -i')`